# Проблемы с библиотекой sockets

Tags: python, pyqt5, сеть, сокеты, чат

Я создаю на pyqt6 чат. С помощью модуля sockets я отправляю сообщения по ip адресу. Тестирую я через ip 127.0.0.1 (loop-back interface) .Когда я нажимаю кнопку "Send", моё сообщение появляется, однако программа завершается. Как это можно исправить?

Ссылка на код: https://github.com/kotKolil/Codnux/blob/main/chat.py